# How to use REPLACE in Select Query? (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, replace

Can I use REPLACE function conditionally?
e.g. I have a query:

```
SELECT diag_type FROM DIAGNOSIS
```

It returns AXIS, AXISI, AXISII, AXIS-C, etc. I want if it returns a result that has AXIS, it makes it AXISIII. Can it be possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean for any substring of AXIS should be replaced

Comment: Nope. Not substring. Substring can be done by this `REPLACE(diag_type, 'AXIS', 'AXISIII')` but I need to replace just AXIS.. Not AXISII or AXISIV or any other AXIS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;with DIAGNOSIS(diag_type) as
(
  select 'AXIS' union all
  select 'AXISI' union all
  select 'AXISII' union all
  select 'AXIS-C'
)

select
  case diag_type
    when 'AXIS' then 'AXISIII'
    else diag_type
  end as diag_type
from DIAGNOSIS
```

Result:

```
diag_type
---------
AXISIII
AXISI
AXISII
AXIS-C
```

Comment: I dnt know exactly that values will be AXISIII,AXISI,AXISII,AXIS-C or some else. I just need to replace AXIS value with AXISIII

Comment: @asma – this query does exactly that. The `;with DIAGNOSIS..` statement is just some sample data that I used to test on. You should only use the `select` statement against your table.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is it to return AXISIII you can just write:

```
SELECT 'AXISIII' FROM DIAGNOSIS WHERE diag_type = 'AXIS'
```

You can also use a CASE-statement to add more options (if you need).

```
SELECT  CASE(diag_type)
    WHEN 'AXIS' THEN 'AXISIII'
    WHEN 'AXIS-C' THEN'AXISIII-C'
    WHEN 'AXISII' THEN'AXISII'
    ELSE    'Something'
    END
FROM DIAGNOSIS
```

Comment: I want all the records remain same but when AXIS come, it must become AXISIII

Comment: if I use this: `WHEN 'AXIS' THEN 'AXISIII'` what about the rest of the values? like AXISI, AXISII etc? I want to select those as well unconditionally.

Comment: You just write... SELECT  CASE(diag_type) WHEN 'AXIS' THEN 'AXISIII' ELSE diag_Type END FROM DIAGNOSIS

Comment: yeah you were right.. I wish I could mark two answers at a time :(